# Highly scalable db schema for recurring events

Tags: events, scalability, scheduling, recurrence

Which is the best way to design a db schema in which store hundreds of thousand events, with recurrencies, and that will support milions of query asking which events will occur in a range of dates?

I mean, designing the tables to describe the model should be not difficult, but doing that in such a way that the huge amount of data can be searched quickly... well, I have no idea of how to do that.

Comment: Just get a faster computer :p

Answer (score 1):

Why not build your datamodel as you normally would (3NF-5NF) and add another layer that is better suited to handle searching like Lucene or Solr?